# Read a Session variable from external server, JQuery, PHP and HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to read a session variable from php script on an external server using ajax...

**1:my Jquery/Ajax call(on localhost)**

```
$.ajax({                                
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://domain.co.za/printsession.php", 
 dataType: "html",
 beforeSend:function()
 {
   $('#results').html('loading...');
 },
 success: function(msg)
 {
  $('#results').html(msg);  
 }

});
```

**2:my php script(on an external sever)**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  echo 'you are logged in as :'.$user;
?>
```

currently is returning only "you are logged in as :"....It is leaving out the session data

Comment: Yes, it should work. There must be something wrong with the script that's setting the session variable.

Comment: Are you sure that domain.co.za allows a cross domain request?

Comment: Checkout with FIREBUG what status it is showing, I mean ajax call status

Comment: thnx alot guys, but i found another alternative i nw use HTML5 localstorage now instead of php Sessions, they way better..mostly fr hybrid mobile Apps i thnk ,bt will do more research..Your comments appreciated.